# Flat Tire Probability Question

Tags: probability, proof-verification

A person just bought new two cars ($4$ tires each). For each tire, the probability of being flattened is $10\%$. In other words, $90\%$ of chance to be a regular, unfaulty tire. The person installs $4$ tires on the first car and then install other $4$ tires on the second car. (After finishing the installation on the first car)

### What would be the probability at least $1$ tire out of $8$ is flattened?

I thought answer was $1-(0.9)^8$, but my professor says it is wrong.

Is someone can help me out to solve it?

Comment: $1-(0.9)^8$ is the probability that it is *not the case that all eight tires are unflattened*.  So the event *is* that at least one is flattened.

Comment: Hmmm I could totally be missing something but I think you're right. Let $X$ be the number of flat tires. Then $X \sim Binomial(n=8, p=.1)$ and so $$P(\text{You have at least one flat})=P(X \ge 1) = 1- P(X=0) = 1 - {8 \choose 0}0.1^00.9^8 = 1-.9^8$$ which is what you came up with

Comment: The answer might be wrong if "finished installing tires on the first car" means "at least four tires were unflattened, so that installation was successful."

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is most likely not one tire but one car i.e what is the probability that at least one of the cars has no working tires?

Ans: case1: only one car has no working tires = 0.1^4(4C0*(0.9)^4+4C1*(0.9)^3(0.1)+4C1*(0.9)^2(0.1)^2+4C1*(0.9)^1(0.1)^3+4C1*(0.1)^4) = 1*0.1^4

As there two cars the probability is 2*0.1^4

But we are counting twice the probability of getting both the cars no working tires, so subtracting 0.1^4*0.1^4 from the above we get the following,

Probability = 19999/100000000 = 1.9999*10^-8

Hope this helps your query.

Comment: Hello @parthu, try to improve your answer by editing it and using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).